# AJAX post to PHP empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have checked the other questions - this is not a duplicate.
I have tried all of the solutions I could find and implement.

I am trying to send data from task.php → showCats.php

task.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("click", ".btnCat", function () {
        var filter = $(this).data("id");

        alert(filter);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'showCats.php',
            data: {'filter': filter},
        });
        $('div.container-fluid').load('showCats.php');
    });

</script>
```

showCats.php:

```
$area = $_POST['filter'];

$sql = "select AID,name,surname,street_name,house_number, area, plz,poster,visible from addresses WHERE area LIKE '$area' AND visible LIKE 'show' ORDER BY AID DESC";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$str = '';

while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $str .= '
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="task col-md-12 well" id='.$res['AID'].'>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnDelete" id='.$res["poster"].' onclick="refresh()" data-id="'.$res['AID'].'">x</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>'. $res["name"].'</span>
                <span>'. $res["surname"].'</span><br>
                <span>'. $res["street_name"].'</span>
                <span>'. $res["house_number"].'</span><br>
                <span>'. $res["plz"].'</span>
                <span>'. $res["area"].'</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}

echo $str;
?>
```

`var_dump($_POST);` returns `NULL`, even though I can see the post value under Developer Tools in Chrome.

My GET:

```
Request URL:https://example.com/showCats.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:xxx:443
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:43:56 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=vudgbb33574tfod2vu48hst830
Host:example.com
Referer:https://example.com/tasks.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

My POST:

```
Request URL:https://example.com/showCats.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:xxx:443
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:43:56 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:12
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=vudgbb33574tfod2vu48hst830
Host:example.com
Origin:https://example.com
Referer:https://example.com/tasks.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
filter:Turgi
```

Comment: [`var_dump($_POST)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) will always RETURN null, but echo the variable.

Comment: Are you sure that the NULL output from `var_dump($_POST)` originates with your your POST request (`ajax`) and not your subsequent GET request (`load`)?

Comment: @showdev I've tried to explain that and i got -2 !!!!

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I know. I think your answer described the likely problem quite well. I'm just trying to clarify that what you've described is the source of OP's actual issue. For what it's worth, I suggest undeleting your answer.

Comment: You've called two requests to `showCats.php`. I don't know why you did it!! Please show two responses (under devtools Chrome) of two requests (one for `GET` [made  by `.load`] and one for `POST` [made by `$.ajax`]). More details will tell your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send data  from `task.php -> showCats.php` ! your code does that very well by using this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'showCats.php',
    data: {'filter': filter},
});
```

The problem is when you do this : `$('div.container-fluid').load('showCats.php');` a `GET` request will be sent to the server! so It's normal to find that `var_dump($_POST)` return NULL.

If you want to show/get the response you can use the `success` event like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'showCats.php',
    data: {'filter': filter},
    //A function to be called if the request succeeds.
    success: function(data) {
       $('div.container-fluid').html(data)
   },
   //A function to be called if the request fails
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       alert('An error occurred:'+error);
   }
});
```

Comment: Ops asking why it is null on the server. This doesn't attempt to answer that.

Comment: Because he is trying to show the returned data by using `load` instead of using the `success` method !!!

Comment: I think OP asked something other than what he meant. He wants to know why his code doesn't work more than why the post array is null. He is trying to debug. This is the root of his problem.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks for explaining, but it is still not working.
Why do you use `$('div.container-fluid').html(data)`? I want to load the php content into that div.

Comment: I think this answer will help topic owner to debug it! Up voted!

Comment: You must remove `$('div.container-fluid').load('showCats.php');` after adding `success` !

Comment: For further reference, see the [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-3) (and documentation) for `ajax()`.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH What do you mean remove it? My code currently looks like your example, but is still not working.

Comment: By 'still not working' you mean the response is empty ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Yes, nothing gets added to the div. Also when I echo the post value in showCats.php - it is empty.

Comment: @ou_snaaksie maybe because your $sql query result is empty ! try to echo the `$area` just to make sure !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH The SQL query has been tested an has 1 result.
`echo $area` returns nothing.
As soon as I hardcode the value in showCats.php everything works(`$area = "Turgi";`).
But I need to get this value from a POST.

Comment: Please add the `error` function as the updated answer and tell me what the result is ! @ou_snaaksie

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Your answer helped! Thanks for all your help. I just restarted the server and now it works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

setting a datatype parameter tells what kind of data you are sending.

```
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
```

I would concur with those comments above.  Loading the program a second time does not report the values of the database call.  Further, wouldn't AJAX normally return values to the calling program with an echo of json_encode, instead of just echoing the variable to a run of the PHP page that does not get viewed?

Comment: Question upvoted.  Not everything has to be groundbreaking.  Troubleshooting counts.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but `dataType` defines the "type of data that you're expecting *back from the server*." See [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: OK, you are correct.  I mentioned it because a little while ago I had a question put to me about the required and optional parts of that call.   I think that dataType was one of the required.  Just reaching for an answer on Stack Overflow.